# Query regarding su command

Tags: linux, command

Can someone explain the difference between su -p (--preserve-environment) and su - when switching user at the command-line?

I'm familiar with "su -" but it's unclear to me how su -p differs, if at all.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [`su`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?su) manpage it says "do not reset environment variables".

Unix shells allow you to store values in variables. It even uses this itself (i.e. the PATH variable saves the location of executables). If you use -p you keep your environment variables, instead of getting the ones from the new user.
(However they might still be overwritten by whatever shell initation scripts that user has..)

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that with `su -p` you can preserve all the personalization you did with your original user. For example, you preserve your alias, your bashrc, profile ...

Answer (score 0):

In simple words:

```
- using "su" you get SuperUser's rights **and** environment 
- using "su -p" you get only SuperUser's rights (the environment stays your own)
```